# Open more than one DataReader on a single OleDbConnection

Tags: c#, ado.net, db2

I am using IBM OLE DB Provider for connecting to DB2.

I can open more than one DataReader on a single OleDbConnection.Does this provider implicitly opens an additional connection for each DataReader.

If so,will this connections closed automatically or stay open until the connection get time-out.

```
  OleDbConnection connection = new (connectionString);
  OleDbDataReader reader = null;
  try
    {
      connection.Open();
      reader = OleDbHelpher.ExecuteNonQuery(connection, CommandType.Text,query1);
      while (reader.Read())
      {
        Console.WriteLine(reader[0].ToString());
      }
      reader.Close();

      reader = OleDbHelpher.ExecuteNonQuery(connection, CommandType.Text,query2);
      while (reader.Read())
      {
        Console.WriteLine(reader[0].ToString());
      }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
     connecton.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a try/finally block the way you have it now, the connection will always be closed.

No, you can't open more than one `DataReader` on a single connection. You will get an exception if you attempt something like this.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> Note that while a DataReader is open, the Connection is in use
>   exclusively by that DataReader. You cannot execute any commands for the Connection, 
>   including creating another DataReader, until the original DataReader
>   is closed.

Instead, open 2 connections (don't worry about the penalty since most likely your connections are pooled anyway) and make sure that you close the connection in a finally block or instead use a [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) statement.